# Change screen resolution from RDC session

Tags: windows-7, macos, remote-desktop, citrix-receiver

I connect remotely to two workstations (different projects) from my OS X (El Capitan; 10.11) computer:

**Client A**

- Citrix Receiver/Viewer for Mac OSX 12.0.0 (321559)
- Microsoft Remote Desktop (Windows; not able to discern the version)
- Windows 7

**Client B**

- Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac OSX (8.0.20)
- Windows Server 2012 R2

In each instance, I am not able to change the remote computer's screen resolution (right click Desktop, choose Screen resolution; displays 'The display settings can't be change from a remote session.'), nor am I able to resize the RDC window itself using the mouse (the Citrix component in the one case makes this more difficult).

Is there another way to do this?  I'm really hoping for a setting on the remote machine that would allow me to resize the RDC window to the desired size.

Comment: You can't adjust the resolution of the host because the RDP client decides the resolution (since it gets it's own desktop rendered, unlike say, VNC).  Change the desired resolution settings in the RDP client before connecting.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/98494/windows-rdp-possible-to-resize-resolution-on-the-fly?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/138140/change-the-default-resolution-of-remote-desktop-connection-mstsc

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Techie007's comments on changing the resolutino in the RDP client before connecting, I noticed when connecting to Server 2012R2 that if you had a previously established console connection, the rdp connection might use that one instead of starting a new session, in which case the resolution will be off.

I noticed this when using Remote Desktop Connection Manager v2.7 when the resolution was set to "Same as client area".

The key to resolving this was to log off the session instead of disconnecting, then log back on.